# Adding data to arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to append data to an `Array` and save using [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache), but it's like I'm doing it wrong. Cause, the data isn't being appended. I keep getting empty array

```
private var teams: Array<Teams> = Array<Teams>()
private var teamResults: [TeamResult]! {
    didSet {
        if teamResults.count <= 0 {
            return
        } else {
            self.teams = []
            for var index = 0; index < teamResults.count; index++ {
                //print(index)
                let categoryResult = teamResults[index]
                if let categoryBackgroundImage = categoryResult["image"] as? PFFile {
                    categoryBackgroundImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                        if let dataGot = data {
                            let image = UIImage(data: dataGot)
                            let appendData = Teams(playing: categoryResult["playing"] as! Bool,
                                name: categoryResult["name"] as! String,
                                position: categoryResult["position"] as! Int,
                                image: image!)
                            //print(appendData.position)
                            self.teams.append(appendData)
                        }
                        print(self.teams.count) <-- I get 0
                    })
                    print(self.teams.count) <-- I get 0
                }
            }
            TMCache.sharedCache().setObject(self.teams, forKey: "Teams")
            self.mainTableView.reloadData()
            for categ in teams {
                print(categ.position)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` works asynchronously. The data is returned later in the block.

You have to put the code to reload the table view into the block and check if the loop is finished.

For example (untested)

```
private var teams: Array<Teams> = Array<Teams>()
private var teamResults: [TeamResult]! {
  didSet {
    if teamResults.count <= 0 {
        return
    } else {
        self.teams = []
        var index : Int
        for index = 0; index < teamResults.count; index++ {
            //print(index)
            let categoryResult = teamResults[index]
            if let categoryBackgroundImage = categoryResult["image"] as? PFFile {
                categoryBackgroundImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                    if let dataGot = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: dataGot)
                        let appendData = Teams(playing: categoryResult["playing"] as! Bool,
                            name: categoryResult["name"] as! String,
                            position: categoryResult["position"] as! Int,
                            image: image!)
                        //print(appendData.position)
                        self.teams.append(appendData)
                        TMCache.sharedCache().setObject(self.category, forKey: "Teams")
                        if index == teamResults.count {
                            self.mainTableView.reloadData()
                            for categ in teams {
                              print(categ.position)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciated